# WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

In my web application I get the following error:

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping
>   for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms
>   UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for
>   'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named
>   jquery(case-sensitive).

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net 2012 Unobtrusive Validation with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452109/asp-net-2012-unobtrusive-validation-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Since .NET 4.5 the validators use data-attributes and bound JavaScript to do the validation work, so .NET expects you to add a script reference for jQuery.

**There are two possible ways to solve the error:**

---

Disable `UnobtrusiveValidationMode`:

Add this to web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

It will work as it worked in previous .NET versions and will just add the necessary JavaScript to your page to make the validators work, instead of looking for the code in your jQuery file. This is the common solution actually.

---

Another solution is to register the script:

In Global.asax `Application_Start` add mapping to your jQuery file path:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", 
        new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path = "~/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js",
            DebugPath = "~/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js",
            CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js",
            CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js"
        });
}
```

---

Some details from MSDN:

> **ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode** Specifies how ASP.NET
> globally enables the built-in validator controls to use unobtrusive
> JavaScript for client-side validation logic.
>
> If this key value is set to "None" [default], the ASP.NET application
> will use the pre-4.5 behavior (JavaScript inline in the pages) for
> client-side validation logic.
>
> If this key value is set to "WebForms", ASP.NET uses HTML5 data-attributes and late bound JavaScript from an added script reference for client-side validation logic.

Comment: the top solution fixed this issue for me, on .Net 4.5.2

Answer (score 9):

To fix this problem on specific page need to set some validation settings when page loading. Write code below in `Page_Load()` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
    }
```

Its work for me in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 7):

I think this is the best solution for this type error. 
So please add below  line. 
Also it work my code when I am using MSVS 2015.

`<configuration>`
      `<appSettings>`
        `<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />`
    `</appSettings>`
`</configuration>`

Comment: This is a better solution. If you add the ScriptManager with path definitions and would like to use JQuery or JS or Ajax from Bootstrap, there might be conflict. I'm sure there is a workaround, but I found this worked better.

Answer (score 3):

Jaqen H'ghar is spot-on. A third way is to:

1. Go to Manage NuGet Packages
2. Install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation
3. Open Global.asax.cs file and add this code inside the Application_Start method

Code that runs on application startup:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition {
    Path = "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
    DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
});
```

Comment: This worked for me (.NET 4.6), but I'm going through a book and I'm working from an "ASP.NET Empty Web Site" project, which doesn't have a Global.asax, so I had to add a "Global Application Class" to the project, which adds the Global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your website go to **property pages** and check both the check-boxes under **Accessibility validation** click on ok. run the website.

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates a problem with the unobtrusive JavaScript validation mode. This issue is not Sitefinity specific and occurs in any standard ASP.NET applications when the project targets .NET 4.5 framework and the pre-4.5 validation is not enabled in the web.config file.

Open the web.config file and make sure that there is a ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode in the app settings:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the accepted answer, I ran into issues with code elsewhere on my site requiring jQuery along with the [Migrate Plugin](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-migrate-plugin).

When the required mapping is added to Global.asax, when loading a page requiring unobtrusive validation (for example a page with the ChangePassword ASP control), the mapped script resource conflicts with the already-loaded jQuery and migrate scripts.

Adding the migrate plugin as a second mapping solves the issue:

```
// required for UnobtrusiveValidationMode introduced since ASP.NET 4.5
var jQueryScriptDefinition = new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
    Path = "~/Plugins/Common/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", DebugPath = "~/Plugins/Common/jquery-3.3.1.js", LoadSuccessExpression = "typeof(window.jQuery) !== 'undefined'"
};
var jQueryMigrateScriptDefinition = new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
    Path = "~/Plugins/Common/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js", DebugPath = "~/Plugins/Common/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js", LoadSuccessExpression = "typeof(window.jQuery) !== 'undefined'"
};
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", jQueryScriptDefinition);
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", jQueryMigrateScriptDefinition);
```