# ASP.NET -- "Server Error in '/' Application" Only when using <asp:RequiredFieldValidator>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I have this code which simply displays a Message followed by a text box and a Required Field Validator:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" Runat="Server">
<div id="MainContent" style="width:75%; float:right; height:600px;" >
    <h1><asp:Label ID="welcome" runat="server"></asp:Label></h1> <br />
    <h3>Fill in the information below</h3> <br /> <br /> <br />

    First Name-: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="20" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
        ErrorMessage="First Name Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Middle Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiddleName" runat="server" MaxLength="20" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMiddleName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMiddleName"
        ErrorMessage="Middle Name Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Last Name--: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" MaxLength="40" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLastName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
        ErrorMessage="Last Name Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Street 1---: <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreet1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStreet1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStreet1"
        ErrorMessage="Street Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Street 2---: <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreet2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" /> 
                <br />
    City-------: <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" MaxLength="20" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCity"
        ErrorMessage="City Name Must be Filled In"/><br />
    State------: <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" MaxLength="2" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvState" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtState"
        ErrorMessage="State Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Zip--------: <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" MaxLength="10" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvZip" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtZip"
        ErrorMessage="Zip Code Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Phone------: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="11" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
        ErrorMessage="Phone Number Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Email------: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="40" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail"
        ErrorMessage="The Email Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Cell Phone-: <asp:TextBox ID="txtCellPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="11" /> 
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCellPhone" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCellPhone"
        ErrorMessage="Cell Phone Number Must be Filled In"/><br />
    Facebook---: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFacebook" runat="server" MaxLength="20" /> 
                <br />

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Btn_Click"/>
    <br /> <br />
</div>
```

However, Whenever I use the  tag I get this error in my browser saying "Server Error in '/' Application". I've never had this issue. Only when I put in the RequiredFieldValidator tags does this happen, otherwise, it is fine. I've never had this problem before and I can't understand what is going on and why using this class gives me an error. [image: Browser Error]

Comment: did you include the jquery as it requested?

Comment: Or disable `UnobtrusiveValidationMode`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error indicated you need to set the Validation setting to UnobtrusiveValidationMode

Add the following code to your web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
          <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
     </appSettings>
```

===========================

Update: This method has always been a quick fix for me. 
The drawback of this solution is for each validator you will get "Inline" javascript code in your HTML. If your page is big these inline javascript will create clutter.

If that's the case take a look here for another solution which you can get rid of inline Javascripts :

[WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230036/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery)