# Odd Variation of the "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error - .NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

I've got an odd variation of the "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". Using .NET Web Forms, I have a `HttpWebRequest` the yields the error, but only after the initial compile. If I simply refresh the webpage, it works fine and does what it needs to. I'd like to find a solution to get rid of the initial error altogether.

I've tried a number of different solutions to prevent the initial error from happening, but have not found any success.

I'm curious if anyone else has seen the error happen in this way? If so, have you found a solution?

- [Solving “Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel” error](https://trailheadtechnology.com/solving-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-error-in-net-4-6-x/)
- [Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel, despite setting ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994464/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-despite-setting-servercertificatevalida)
- [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: have you tried to use another framework.

Comment: Yes, was originally on 4.0, then 4.5.2, now running on 4.7. To my understanding, this shouldn't be an issue with 4.7 (and it's not, for 99% of the requests), it's just an issue after recompiling or when the AppPool recycles.

Comment: Additionally, I used IIS Crypto to get rid of old protocols and make sure all current protocols are enabled.

Comment: try 4.8 and 7,.0 or 8.9, but i thing that your server has only old vulnerable ssl/tls version, so you should first look  at the webseerver which protcolls he supports, if you can not upgrade the server, you need to downgrade the framework

Comment: This is a .NET web application, so I don't believe that I can go beyond 4.8. I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: you could try this to see what the server and app are communicating https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142939/determine-ssl-tls-version-using-wireshark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the title, I had a odd situation where I'd get this error "**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**", but only after being recompiled or after the AppPool would recycle. After the first/initial error, all subsequent requests would work fine, until the next recompile or AppPool recyle.

Going back to the framework suggestions, I reviewed the `targetFramework` which was 4.7. I reviewed the `web.config` and noticed that I did not have `targetFramework` set inside the `httpRuntime` tag (in fact, I didn't even have the httpRuntime tag. Adding the following solved the issue - no more errors on the initial load:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
    ...
```

Note: I did have `targetFramework` set within my  tag, but adding the `<httpRuntime/>` tag with `targetFramework="4.7"` resolved the problem.

This change did cause another issue with `UnobtrusiveValidation` mode, but that was easily solved by following this suggestion: [WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230036/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery)